# Can I change the name of my replica set while mongod processes are running?

Tags: mongodb

If so, how?

When I first created the replica set, I chose a confusing name; I'd like to change it now.

The replica set name is mentioned in `/etc/mongod.conf`, and I'm not sure when it reads/rereads that. Since the replica set name can also be passed in as a command-line parameter, I'm assuming (and currently testing) the following:

- it just uses replica set name once on startup while syncing up with other nodes
- I have to reconfigure, stop, change `replSet` CLI argument or `replSet` value in `/etc/mongod.conf`, then restart

In other words, I'm assuming the answer to my original question is "no, you must restart" or "no, replica set name is immutable". I'll probably figure this out soon enough since I'm trying it locally.

Comment: No, you can not do that. Why would you want to, anyway?

Comment: I'll mention why in my post. If you're sure "no" is the answer, why not just answer the question?

Comment: I forgot the exact procedure to change RS name (that's why I didn't post this as an answer), but it certainly involves restarting mongod and deleting some data.

Comment: Deleting some data? Yikes! I sure hope not.

Comment: cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[1].host = "mongodb1.example.net:27017"
rs.reconfig(cfg)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's how to do it with downtime:

1. Stop all the servers

   - If authentication is enabled, make sure it is disabled or changes to the local.system.replset collection may not be authorized.
2. Start up each server without the --replSet option, pointing at the correct data directory.
3. Update the local.system.replset doc on each server with the new replica set name.  *You have to change every server here.*
   Here is how to update local.system.replset in mongo shell:

   ```
   use local  
   var doc = db.system.replset.findOne()  
   doc._id = 'NewReplicaSetName'
   db.system.replset.save(doc)  
   db.system.replset.remove({_id:'OldReplicaSetName'})
   ```
4. Shut them down again.
5. Change the /etc/mongod.conf replSet option to the new name on all the servers.
6. Start them all up with the original options.

Comment: I did step 3 like so: cut all JSON returned from `db.system.replset.find()` in the `mongo` shell, paste in text editor, change `_id` value, use edited JSON in `db.system.replset.update({}, <NEW_JSON>)`.

Comment: You'll need to use findOne, not find, but other than that sounds good.

Comment: These steps don't appear to work any longer.  I receive this error below when attempting the update command.

WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 16837,
                "errmsg" : "The _id field cannot be changed from {_id: \"set1\"} to {_id: \"qa2set1\"}."
        }
})

Comment: i also receive the following error:  "errmsg" : "The _id field cannot be changed from {_id: \"rs1\"} to {_id: \"dev1\"}."

Comment: "The _id field cannot be changed" type of errors should be resolved if you follow the revised process above.

Comment: You may need to start mongod on the Terminal by entering command (not use config file): `mongod --dbpath ~/path/to/your/app/data`

Comment: That’s why you should use save/insert and delete and not update.

Answer (score 8):

kristina's answer is good, but step 3 could use a little more explanation. In your mongo shell, edit db.system.replset like this:

```
use local
var doc = db.system.replset.findOne()
doc._id = 'NewReplicaSetName'
db.system.replset.save(doc)
db.system.replset.remove({_id:'OldReplicaSetName'})
```

Comment: You should improve the original answer if you think you are adding value.

Answer (score 0):

No.

See [thread "Change replica set name" in mongodb-user](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/VLuGAJHSFdQ/discussion)... Kristina Chodorow asserts that downtime is necessary.

I'll add instructions on how to change the replica set name here (with downtime) once I figure it out (unless someone else beats me to it).

Comment: There used to be an official wiki page, if I'm not mistaken.